# Webserver using noip on rastberry pi

Tags: webserver, portforwarding

Im using a pi and I've made a webpage using the yeoman generator "angular". Backend is made in springboot and running on port 8080 and the frontend is a angular app running on port 9000.

So here is the question. 
I've setup the noip according to some guide (dont have the adress, month ago or so). And I've tried forward the ports 22 -> 22, for ssh and 3389 for remote desktop. All works fine. And I added på 80 (WAN) going to 9000 (LAN) to reach the webpage but that doesent work att all.

I've tried opening up ports 8080 -> 9000 and 9000 -> 9000 but it dosent seem to work. 
I've also tried different webbrowsers ending with different ports, 
my-dns:80 
my-dns:8080 
my-dns:9000

Nothing works. :(

**update**

Now I get this message going against my-dns:8080

[image]

Comment: according to a portscanner port 80 is closed when looking in the pi

Comment: Have you tried to check the listening ip of the server? I guess springboot in your case. It should listen on 0.0.0.0, which means all network interfaces